# Get the most accurate location of user

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

I am a student and my final year project is an android application.
My application, i need to use current latest location of user at the very first when the application launch start.

I was facing problem that when i start my application it gives me the last known location which is very poor,but i need accurate and quickly current(updated) location of the user when application start.
How can i do it?

Please Help me in solving my this problem.

I will be very thanks full to you.

Comment: I want to to get latest location of user with less latency and more accurate when first time application start.

Comment: Please post some code.